# Before not inheriting color from parent element

Tags: html, css, inheritance, pseudo-element

How do I make the 'before' triangle inherit the color from the square? `Color:inherit`, `border-color:inherit`, `background-color:inherit` didn't work out.

```css
.tag {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 150px;
  display: block;
  width: 290px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  border-color: orange;
}

.tag:before {
  color: orange;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="tag">
  16,00 €
</div>
```

Comment: Border colors aren't inheritable properties, you just have to define them  on the pseudo element. Sucks...but it just has to be done.

Comment: What if the user enters some color code, that is applied via variable into HTML? as in <div class="tag" style="color: <?php echo $uservariable?>">Price</div>, how do I select the pseudo element then?

Comment: I'm assuming you don't mean `color` but `border-color`. It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I don't know if it should be color, border color or background color. Just wanted to show how the variable is used (and why the :before needs to inherit it)

Comment: The pseudo-element **can't** inherit a border-color it's not an inheritable property in this instance. If you need some automatic system you're looking at Javascript to change the CSS.

Comment: Yup, I guess that's the only way. Kind of sad :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use something like this which requires an extra element as you have to reset the color of the text.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vkw281gL/5/)

Text color is inherited and has it's own variable name `currentColor` which can be used on child elements (and pseudo- elements).

So we add an internal `span` to the div and apply a set text color to the div.

We have to reset the color for the span (otherwise it would be invisible) and refer to the background and borders by reference to the `currentColor`.

```css
 .tag {
     position:absolute;
     top:20px;
     left:150px;
     display:block;
     color:green;
     width:290px;
     height:100px;
     background-color: currentColor
 }
 span {
     color:black;
 }
 .tag:before {
     content:"";
     position:absolute;
     left:-50px;
     border-top: 50px solid transparent;
     border-right: 50px solid currentColor;
     border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
 }
```

```html
<div class="tag"> 
    <span>16,00 €</span>
</div>
```